# Llamar a un procedure de la clase invocadora

Tags: delphi

Soy nuevo en delphi/free pascal y creo que tengo un error de concepto, pues estoy acostumbrado a java y quizás no se puedan plantear las cosas de la misma forma. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Estoy utilizando Lazarus v1.6RC1.

Tengo una clase `TControl` en una `unit uControl` y una clase `TRed` en una `unit TRed`. La unit `uControl` tiene la `unit uRed` en uses. La case `TControl` tiene un atributo llamado `FRed`, cuyo tipo es `TRed` (es una instancia de `TRed`). El caso es que en un momento dado, necesito llamar a un *procedure* de `TControl` desde `TRed`. Mi intención es tener acceso a la instancia de `TControl` desde `TRed`, para poder acceder a sus métodos, eso es algo que hacía en java, pero aquí no parece funcionar. Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

Clase `TControl`:

```
TControl = class(TObject)
    procedure procesaEntradaRed(pComando : TComando)
public
    FRed : TRed;
```

Clase `TRed`:

```
TRed = class(TObject)
    constructor Create(pControl : TControl)
public
    FControl : TControl;
```

Cuando instacio `TRed` en `TControl` lo hago así:

```
FRed := TRed.Create(Self);
```

Y el constructor de `TRed` es así:

```
constructor TRed.Create(pControl : TControl)
begin
    FControl := pControl;
end;
```

La llamada en la que tengo el error es esta:

```
FControl.procesaEntradaRed(lComando);
```

El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

> uRed.pas(662,12) Error: identifier idents no member
>   "procesaEntradaRed"

He intentado ver qué métodos eran visibles de `TControl` desde `TRed`, y ninguno de los que he creado en `TControl` es visible, aunque sí los métodos propios de `TObject`.

He puesto sólo las partes del código que intervienen en el problema para ser conciso.

Gracias de antemano y perdón por la inexperiencia.

**EDIT:**

La línea donde hago la llamada se encuentra en `uRed`, al final de un procedure cuya declaración es:

```
procedure TRed.UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread; const AData: TidBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
```

Sin embargo, al comentar esa línea, salta error al instanciar TRed, pasando Self como parámetro:

```
FRed := TRed.Create(Self);
```

El error es el siguiente:

> uControl.pas(146,69) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 3: Got > >"UCONTROL.TControl", expected "CONTROLS.TControl"

Pone que falla el parámetro 3, es porque además paso 2 strings, no las muestro para no confundir.

El fallo parece estar en el Self, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Esta llamada, si la has colocado en el lugar correcto no parece que tenga que dar ese error.
¿Exactamente dónde está esa llamada?
¿Puedes dar más detalles de dónde está esa llamada?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. He editado la pregunta para responderte. Aunque al comentar la línea el error salta al instanciar TRed, concretamente en Self.

Comment: Parece que tienes problemas porque estás utilizando el mismo nombre de la clase TControl, que es una clase base en Delphi.
De ahí el error. Tee está diciendo que el parámetro de UControl.pas (tu clase) no es del mismo tipo que el de Controls.pas (Clase de Delphi).

Comment: En el comentario anterior te he puesto Delphi, pero imagino que debe ser igual en Lazarus. Cambia tu clase TControl y ponle otro nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de hacerlo, he renombrado a TControlTerminal y ya no da ese error. Sin embargo ahora en la unit uRed, al declarar FControl : TControlTerminal salta identifier not found "TControlTerminal". Supongo que es porque en uRed no tengo uControl en los uses, y la clase no es visible para TRed.

Comment: Ya he descubierto cómo hacerlo, la solución fue declarar en TRed FControl : TObject; y al hacer la llamada en TRed hacer un cast, TControlTerminal(FControl).procesaEntradaRed(lComando); 
Esto ya era otro problema aparte, muchas gracias por ayudarme a salir del atasco!

Comment: @DanielRivers Sería interesante que publicaras la respuesta para futuros lectores que pudieran beneficiarse con esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que hay varias clases con el mismo nombre dentro de la visibilidad y no calificas correctamente el nombre de la clase que quieres referenciar, y en realidad estás declarando otra.

Vamos a dividir una historia larga en varias pequeñas.

## TControl

TControl es una clase ya declarada en la unidad Controls. Es de hecho, bastante *popular*, ya que es el origen de todos los *controles* en FPC, así como lo es en la VCL de Delphi.

Es decir, en FPC, al igual que en la VCL, cualquier control (es decir, cualquier cosa que el usuario pueda ver en su pantalla), hereda directa o indirectamente de TControl. Yo sigo la recomendación de no declarar otras clases con los mismos nombres que las clases de las bibliotecas de la propia herramienta: VCL/RTL/FMX, y menos de las clases que son base de la jerarquía de clases.

Pero Delphi/FPC si soporta distintas clases con el mismo nombre. Para eso, veamos.

## Reglas de identificadores con el mismo nombre.

En Delphi/FPC puedes declarar tipos de datos y variables con el mismo nombre, si están en distintos niveles de visibilidad o en distintas unidades.

En caso de estar en distintas unidades, la [documentación](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Programs_and_Units#Multiple_and_Indirect_Unit_References) nos dice (traducción libre realizada por mi):

> El orden en que las unidades aparecen en la clausula `uses` determina el orden de su inicialización y afecta la manera en que los identificadores son ubicados por el compilador. Si dos unidades declaran una variable, constante, tipo, procedimiento o función con el mismo nombre, el compilador utilizará el de la unidad que aparezca de último en la clausula `uses`. (Para tener acceso al identificador en la otra unidad, debes añadir el calificador: `NombreUnidad.Identificador`.

Volviendo a tu pregunta:

En tu caso, hay dos unidades que contienen la Clase TControl, para resumir, digamos que son:

```
unit uControl;
interface

type
  TControl = class(TObject)
  //etcetera
  end;
```

y además tenemos esta otra, que es parte de la biblioteca visual de FPC.

```
unit Controls
interface

type
  TControl = class(TComponent)
  //etcetera
```

Dado que utilizas ambas unidades en la unidad donde declaras la clase `TRed`, o de otra forma no tendrías este problema, las posibles soluciones son:

- **más recomendado**: cambiar el nombre de tu clase, por ejemplo de `TControl` a `TMiControl`.
- cambiar el orden en que se listan las unidades en la clausula `uses`, para que la unidad uControl aparezca después de la unidad Controls.

  `uses`
  `UnaUnidad, OtraUnidad, Controls, uControl;`
- **recomendado**: Calificar el nombre de la unidad, donde declaras el miembro de clase, así no dependes del orden de la clausula uses ni hay ambigüedad en las declaraciones

Tu código luciría así:

```
TRed = class(TObject)
    constructor Create(pControl : uControl.TControl)
public
    FControl : uControl.TControl;
```